# Detect keypresses interacting with the browser's autocomplete menu

Tags: javascript

I have a `jquery.keypress` on a `text input`, and `keypresses` that are interacting with the browser's autocomplete are all firing the event. Is there a way to tell if (for instance) enter was hit in the input as opposed to in its autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: What are your `keypress` event listener(s) designed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input field in your form and check to see if it is set to determine if the form was submitted.